# Can I turn a java self signed certificate trusted to Java accept certificate automatically

Tags: java, applet, certificate, keytool, signed-applet

I create a self-signed certificate using keytool. I'm use this certificate to run a applet that I developed, but the java in my PC or othres PCs request a autorization to run the applet, beacause the certificate is a self-signerd certificate.
How i resolve this, to run automatically im my PC and others PCs?

Comment: Buy a certificate for your applicatoin.

Comment: But after following the sage advice of @Braiam, note that.. *"How i resolve this, to run automatically.."* that will never happen.  ***Every*** applet will cause a prompt to be presented to the end user.

Comment: This behavior can be changed by altering your security policy, but generally if the CA that signed your cert is trusted by the system running the applet, then it will run without a prompt.  If you create your own root CA (self-signed cert), then it will not be trusted by any commercial software.